# smallest possible valid sql server statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Just wanted to know if **select 1** is the smallest possible valid sql server statement or is there any other statement. i am using `SQL SERVER 2012`.

Comment: `;`, unless you are looking to return something to the client.

Comment: May we ask why you are asking this question?

Comment: Via using SSMS, the smallest valid SQL Server is just space ` `

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:  i was bored and for knowledge sake.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just trivia.

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored procedure with a name length of 1 character and run it:

```
create proc a
as
print 'Small';

go

a   --1 char statement
```

Answer (score 0):

> Go

not sure what you want to achieve or its quiz question

Comment: Not a SQL statement though, its a directive (configurable) to SSMS

Answer (score 0):

This is my smallest ever answer:

```
exec('')
```